# Can't instal Scrapy/Twisted

Tags: python, utf-8, scrapy, twisted, decode

When I use "pip install" to install scrapy for Python on Windows, I request this feedback:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\limin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb6 in position 30: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\limin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\limin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\limin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\limin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\users\limin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\limin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb6 in position 30: invalid start byte
```

I know it maybe a coding problem, but I don't know how to solve it. 
Who can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could use [anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/).
From the scrapy [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#anaconda):
_Using Anaconda is an alternative to using a virtualenv and installing with pip.
For Windows users, or if you have issues installing through pip, this is the recommended way to install Scrapy._

Answer (score 1):

> Scrapy runs on Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 or above (except on Windows where Python 3 is not supported yet).

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. It's worth a chance to use Anaconda, which is also stated in the Scrapy docs, if you're particularly hell bent on using Python 3.6. Or if it's urgent, you can use Python 2.7 and `pip install scrapy`. From my experience, Python 2.7 works a lot better when in comes to Scrapy.