# Pip install Scrapy "codec can't decode byte"

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, pip, twisted

I'm trying hard to install Scrapy, first time I tried I've get error about vcvarsall.bat, I was trying some solutions but nothing worked so I reinstall Visual Studio Community 2017 and dev tools, and now I'm getting error that codec can't decode byte [Here is the full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbIoF.png). Please help me find a solution to this problem.

EDIT: Using Anaconda solved my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't instal Scrapy/Twisted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903714/cant-instal-scrapy-twisted)

Comment: What commands are you using to try to install it? What platform are you on? Please add to your answer.

Comment: @AnEpicPerson I'm using Windows 10, and the commands I used is "pip install Scrapy or second time I used downloaded .whl file"

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, and the specs above to your question. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Installing Anaconda solved the problem.